# How to to open a program with CreateProcess if only its name is known?

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

Like in the following example I'm trying to start Googles Chrome browser from a Windows application using the Windows API function CreateProcess.

The problem I have is that I dont know the path to the Chrome application (or any other application in the Program path). How can I get this?

In the code below I commented three different examples. In case I start "calc", the Calculator is started as it is in the Windows/System32 path. In case I start Chrome with the full path to the application it runs too. But if I omit the path and just try to start "chrome" I get an error #2.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>

void _tmain()
{

    char* cmd = "calc"; // works... calc.exe is in windows/system32 
    // char* cmd = "chrome"; // doesn't work... how can I add the path if it's not known (e.g. windows installed on D:\)
    // char* cmd = "c:/program files (x86)/google/chrome/application/chrome"; // works (even without extension .exe)

    STARTUPINFO si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

    ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));

    // Start the child process. 
    if (!CreateProcess(NULL,   // No module name (use command line)
        cmd,            // Command line
        NULL,           // Process handle not inheritable
        NULL,           // Thread handle not inheritable
        FALSE,          // Set handle inheritance to FALSE
        0,              // No creation flags
        NULL,           // Use parent's environment block
        NULL,           // Use parent's starting directory 
        &si,            // Pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
        &pi)           // Pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION structure
        )
    {
        printf("CreateProcess failed (%d).\n", GetLastError());
        return;
    }

    // Wait until child process exits.
    WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);

    // Close process and thread handles. 
    CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
}
```

Note: if I enter "chrome" (without the quotes) in the Windows Run command window, Chrome starts too. What I'm looking for is the same functionality. However, my application can reside anywhere and is not necessarily located on the same drive as Chrome.

Comment: try `system("path")` to see content of PATH env.variable when your application is working

Comment: What happens in a cmd console when you type `calc` and when you type `chrome`?

Comment: I just had a need for something similar, and solved the problem by calling `PathFindOnPath` to find the full path before calling `CreateProcess`. But in this specific case, for wanting to launch the Chrome browser, I think David Heffernan's answer is better. I would also ask that you reconsider the idea of launching Chrome explicitly. What if the user prefers a different browser, like Firefox or Opera? Just use ShellExecuteEx to launch the web page or HTML document, allowing the user's default browser to open it, whatever that may be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really must use `CreateProcess` then you will need to find out where it is installed and pass the full path to the executable. That's going to require some registry hacking.

However, I feel that there is an easier and more robust way. Chrome registers itself in the [AppPaths](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ee872121.aspx#appPaths) registry so [`ShellExecuteEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762154.aspx) with the file specified as `L"chrome"` and the default verb will do the job.

Comment: @david-hefferman: as I need access to process information I must use CreateProcess. However, you brought me on the right track. In my solution I finally use RegOpenKeyEx to get a handle to the registry key and then get the value to the path out of it using RegQueryValueEx. Not as trivial as I expected, but it works great.

Comment: Not so. You can obtain a process handle from ShellExecuteEx.

Comment: What I'm interested in is the PROCESS_INFORMATION structure. I didn't know (and still dont know) how to get this with ShellExecuteEx. If it's possible, it would probably have been easier. However, once I've got the idea how to do it, it was only a few lines of code away.

Comment: @ShyRobbiani the only info that `PROCESS_INFORMATION` gives you is the process id+handle and thread id+handle. `ShellExecuteEx` can give you the process handle if you use `SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS`. The other values can be gotten from the process handle using `GetProcessId()`, `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot()`/`Thread32First()` (see [Enumerating threads in a process](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20060223-14/?p=32173)), and `OpenThread()`.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely to be unrelated to WinAPI and the `CreateProcess` function, but only to the environment variable `PATH`. By default, it contains the path for all standard windows commands like `calc` or `notepad`, but you must add the path for other commands that you add later, be it under Program Files or anywhere else.

What to do:

- carefully note the actual path of `chrome`
- open Control Panel / System / Advanced system parameters
- click Environment variables: you will find a PATH (case does not matter) in user and system variables.
- add the path for chrome on one (system is meant meant for all users)

It should now be possible to launch chrome without specifying its full path.

NB: unsure for the actual labels for all of the above, my own box speaks french...

Comment: *"calc"* or *"notepad"* aren't commands. They are programs, or applications.

Answer (score 0):

I have two ideas

1. I found this shortcut down below on my PC, I think you can get this .lnk if you installed Google Chrome correctly.

C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Google Chrome.lnk

2. You can search "Google\Chrome\Application" in the regedit.exe. I guess there is a string key that can get the full path. but you must be careful, there are so many versions of google chrome, and it might have different environments of Windows.